# is_writable returns false for NFS-share, even though it is writable for the user www-data

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, nfs

I have a relative folder 'files/crm-upload', where i want to upload files. My code checks, whether is_writable() is true and only proceeds if this is the case.

The folder is mounted as a NFS share with rw and sec=sys.

I have written a test script, which i also execute on the apache to see access rights, it's result:

```
files/crm-upload/php_touch modification time has been changed to present time 
My effective UID is 33 but my UID is really 33
files/crm-upload/ is owned by 33 and has permissions 40777
is_readable('files/crm-upload/') gives true
is_readable('files/crm-upload/php_touch') gives true
is_writable('files/crm-upload/') gives false
is_writable('files/crm-upload/php_touch') gives true
is_writable('files/crm-upload/25/') gives true
is_writable('files/images/') gives true
file_exists('files/crm-upload/') gives true
file_exists('files/crm-upload/php_touch') gives true
Some stat uids: 

files/crm-upload/: 33
files/crm-upload/php_touch: 33
files/images/: 33
```

So:

- touching a file on the share works
- uids are correct
- dir has correct permissions
- is_writable for subfolders and files on the share returns true

How can this be, that only the root folder of the mounted share is not writable and everything else is?

It is a ubuntu 18.04. client, there is no SELinux running...

Comment: What is the whole path of that folder?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa /var/www/html/iah/files/crm-upload

Comment: And by root folder which folder do you mean?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa the crm-upload folder

Comment: Can you do a `ls -la` on it?

Comment: files/crm-upload/ is owned by 33 and has permissions 40777.
what information do you need?

Comment: Sometimes it's not just permission issues. you may need to configure Apparmor to be able to access paths that are not in /var/www. Happened to me a few months ago

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have `40777`. I think you have `4777` or `0777`

Use `2777` or `7777`

See more on https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits

Comment: ls -lah on the directory "files/crm-upload" reveals:
`drwxrwxrwx 152 www-data www-data 4,0K Feb 27 10:26 .`.

Also file-permissions "40777" were determined using `sprintf('%o', fileperms($dirname))` in PHP.